# Aerospike - Scans with “done(abandoned-unknown)” status

Tags: scala, aerospike, java-client

Once I updated aerospike server and java client I am having a strange status **"done(abandoned-unknown)"** on aql > show scans

[image]

When query a set with a few registries is having a **"done(ok)"**, but when query a bigger set is having the **"done(abandoned-unknown)"**.

This behaviour is happening when aerospike server runs on Redhat, but if it is running on Mac with vagrant is having **"active(ok)"** with job_status **"IN_PROGRESS"** and blocks.

The code running is a simple scala code like:

```scala
  object Simple {
  var nodeList: Array[Node] = empty

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val initialHost: String = "XXX.XX.XX.XX:3000"
    val namespace: String = "test"
    val set: String = "hundred"
//    val set: String = "hundred_thousand"
    val select: String = "select * from %s.%s".format(namespace, set)

    val policy = new ClientPolicy()
    val splitHost = initialHost.split(":")
    val client = new AerospikeClient(policy, splitHost(0), splitHost(1).toInt)

    try {
      nodeList = client.getNodes
      val stmt = new Statement()
      stmt.setNamespace(namespace)
      stmt.setSetName(set)

      val recs: RecordSet = client.queryNode(client.queryPolicyDefault, stmt, nodeList.head)
      try {
        val iterator = recs.iterator()
        if (iterator.hasNext) {
          val record = iterator.next().record
          println(record)
        }
      } finally {
        recs.close()
      }
    }
    finally {
      client.close()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Answered on the Aerospike forum on September 16; recopying the answer here for completeness)

This is a set scan. You can troubleshoot by looking at the aerospike.log, and grep for "(scan)", which will give info similar to -

```
Sep 14 2015 22:58:05 GMT: INFO (scan): (thr_tscan.c::871) scan job received
....
Sep 14 2015 22:58:06 GMT: INFO (scan): (thr_tscan.c::387) SCAN JOB DONE
```